# Strange pattern at matplotlib, during simple scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, math

i am trying to analize films data, there two key parameters:

"rating" -> y-axis - float from 0 to 10 with 2 digits after dot, like 9.87

"votes_count" - x-axis - integer

To be more demonstrative i decide to flip the rating using formula 1/(11-rating), to see more clear films with bests scores, this formula maybe from series of "Braking Bad" where dr. Haisenberg explain that the difference between 99% meth and 99.9% is not 0.9% - the difference is in 10 times more clean product, so can some one explain why i see this strange pattern on scatter plot?

[image: pattern]

[image]

[image]

```
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# csv headers
# cast,date,film_id,film_name,film_rating,film_rating_count,film_url,genre,image_url,imdb,producer


with open("films.csv", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    film_list = []
    for film in reader:
        film["film_rating"] = float(film["film_rating"])
        film["film_rating_count"] = int(film["film_rating_count"])
        if film["imdb"]:
            film["imdb"] = float(film["imdb"])
        film_list.append(film)

film_rating_data = (
    (film["film_rating_count"], 1 / (11 - film["film_rating"])) for film in film_list
)

# scatter plot
plt.scatter(*zip(*film_rating_data))
plt.show()
```

and a row from csv for example

```
cast,date,film_id,film_name,film_rating,film_rating_count,film_url,genre,image_url,imdb,producer
#Дэвид_Гаан #Мартин_Гор #Эндрю_Флетчер #Кристиан_Эйгнер #Питер_Гордено #Depeche_Mode,22 сентября #2006года #2000s,49136,Depeche Mode: Touring the Angel - Live in Milan,8.83,30,http://kinopub.me/films/concert/49136-depeche-mode-touring-the-angel-live-in-milan-2006.html,#Концерт #Музыкальные #Зарубежные,http://static.hdrezka.sx/i/2022/5/29/q40013055c1b0ua90a97h.jpg,8.6,#Блу_Лич
#Эдвард_Нортон #Брэд_Питт #Хелена_Бонем_Картер #Мит_Лоаф #Зэк_Гренье #Холт_Маккэллани #Джаред_Лето #Эйон_Бэйли #Ричмонд_Аркетт #Дэвид_Эндрюс,10 сентября #1999года #1990s,787,Бойцовский клуб,9.37,10882,http://kinopub.me/films/drama/787-boycovskiy-klub-1999.html,#Драмы #Триллеры #Криминал #Зарубежные,http://static.hdrezka.sx/i/2013/11/30/m33c30ddfb881gn13z89a.jpg,8.8,#Дэвид_Финчер
#Леонид_Парфенов #Михаил_Гусев #Сергей_Ланбамин #Наталья_Новикова #Юлия_Сорокина #Наталия_Куликова,12 июня #2014года #2010s,22652,Цвет нации,7.71,327,http://kinopub.me/films/documentary/22652-cvet-nacii-2013.html,#Документальные #Биографические #Исторические #Русские,http://static.hdrezka.sx/i/2016/11/21/wa3fc92af681bor23q44s.jpg,8.2,#Сергей_Нурмамед
#Майкл_Дж__Фокс #Кристофер_Ллойд #Лиа_Томпсон #Криспин_Гловер #Томас_Ф__Уилсон #Клодия_Уэллс #Марк_МакКлюр #Уэнди_Джо_Спербер #Джордж_ДиЧенцо #Фрэнсис_Ли_МакКейн,3 июля #1985года #1980s,1171,Назад в будущее,9.65,5224,http://kinopub.me/films/adventures/1171-nazad-v-buduschee-1985.html,#Приключения #Фантастика #Комедии #Зарубежные,http://static.hdrezka.sx/i/2021/2/21/w399fb56a333fke75x37l.jpeg,8.5,#Роберт_Земекис
```

Comment: I think the weird pattern might come from inhomogeneity in the possible precision of the ratings. For instance, with y = 1 / (11 - r), a value y = 0.5 corresponds to r = 9, which is a round value and thus a pretty common rating if the number of voters is low. But a value y = 0.58 corresponds to r = 9.276, which is maybe much harder to obtain as an average of ratings.

Comment: Assuming you didn't make any mistake in your code and the ratings are really the numbers from 0 to 10 that you expect, this is a very interesting question, but probably better suited for stats.stackexchange.com than for stackoverflow.com . It has nothing to do with matplotlib, and only depends on the distribution of ratings. Of course, that's assuming there are no mistakes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your math or calculation is wrong.
You state the `y-axis` is `11/(Rating)`where Rating is `[0;10]`

1. How do you handle `11/0`?
2. `11/10 =1.1`, `11/1=11` This does not match the pictured values.

Comment: it's zoomed part of whole picture, edited the post and add some more images, icluding full

Comment: and sorry, there missinformation, the formula is 1/11-rating so handling divizion by zero is not needed